# AWS IAM createrole is denied despite giving the right permission to the user

Tags: aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam

I have given my user role following custom permission

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "iam:CreateRole",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

And when this user is deploying a cloudformation stack which creates an IAM role, I get following error message

```
failed to create CloudFormation stack, rollback requested (ROLLBACK_COMPLETE):

 ["The following resource(s) failed to create: [SecretsManagerRDSPostgreSQLRotationSingleUserRole].
 Rollback requested by user." "API: iam:CreateRole User: arn:aws:iam::account:user/username

 is not authorized to perform:
 iam:CreateRole on resource: arn:aws:iam::account:role/role_name
 with an explicit deny in an identity-based policy"
```

Comment: How is this CF stack deployed, via CLI, UI, ...?

Comment: I am using terraform aws provider

Comment: And where is the provider running?

Comment: The provider needs to assume a role that has a iam:CreateRole permission

Comment: It is assuming that role.. See the error message that I pasted. IAM compailing the `user` is not able to do `iam:CreateRole` but I have assigned the `createRole` permission to `user`